# serve a single file irrespective of the location match in nginx

Tags: nginx

My current configuration is

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name some.com;

    location /{
       root /var/www;
       index index.html;
    }
}
```

This matches

`/` -> `/var/www/index.html`

`/container` -> `/var/www/container/index.html`

I expect the location match not to be appended to the root. So the matching will be

`/` -> `/var/www/index.html`

`/container` -> `/var/www/index.html`

It will be same irrespective of the location, and I'll handle the render dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual method is to use `try_files` to provide a default URI:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name some.com;

    root /var/www;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.